Only seeing provisional headers in the browser devtools
I keep on getting CORs errors. When I try to debug them in the devtools console, I see the following output:

I can't get rid of the error. Even when hard refreshing to get rid of the cache.
How can I see the full request headers?
For context, I am fetching the resource using the browser's fetch API.

When the request encounters a CORS error, yes, that's what it'll look like. The solution is to properly add CORS response headers…!? If you need a testing tool for debugging the headers, use Postman or other external tools.
